# How do you send only a couple of results (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discrim commands for my discord bot

here is the command

```
      const query = args[1];
            if (!query) return message.channel.send("Please include a discriminator! | Usage: !discrim {your tag} | eg: !discrim 0001");

            const users = bot.users.cache.filter(user => user.discriminator === query).map(m => m.tag);
            if (!users.length) return message.channel.send(`No users found with discriminator **#${query}**!`);

    
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(`${users.length} Users found with discriminator #${query}`)
                        .setDescription(users.join("\n"))
                    message.channel.send(embed)
```

The problem is that there is a description character limit, so when it reaches the limit it sends an error because there are many people with the same discrim. How do I make it so it will show only, for example, 6 results?

Comment: Is it possible to use `slice` like `.setDescription(users.slice(0,n).join("\n"))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop that creates new fields using the `#addField` method, then you could run that using `users[i]` to populate the embed.

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle(`${users.length} Users found with discriminator #${query}`)

var i;
for (i = 0; i < users.length - 1; i++) {
  embed.addField('User:', `${users[i]}`) // for loop to iterate through users
}

message.channel.send(embed) // send the built embed
```

There is an embed field limit, but you can counteract that with multiple embeds, or an embed menu (moved with emoji reactions etc)